# how to put single image from server into my imageview using volly in android?

Tags: android, networkimageview

[image]
[image]

I have read a lot about fetching images from server and put it in  `listview` like that but here for activity i need to have single image from serve which should fit into all devices perfectly.how can i do this as i am new to android so dont know much about that..kindly help?And if can give any example then that would be very helpful.

here is my MainActivity.class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.android.volley.Request;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        FragmentTwo.OnFragmentInteractionListener

{
    ImageView im1, im2, im3;
    ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    ImageView mImageView;
    // The URL for the image that is being loaded.
    private static final String IMAGE_URL =
            "http://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        im1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.ms1);


        ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(IMAGE_URL, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {
                im1.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(imageRequest);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            Class fragmentClass = null;
            fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        }
        im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // User chose the "Settings" item, show the app settings UI...


            case R.id.action_cart:


                Intent ibs = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddToCart.class);
                ibs.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(ibs);
                finish();
                break;
            // User chose the "Favorite" action, mark the current item
            // as a favorite...


            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
        return true;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        if (id == R.id.br_menu) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.tr_ordr) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.pl_ordr) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.profl) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.addr) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.crds) {
            fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }




}
```

for m1 i need to set the imageview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ImageRequest` of `Volley` to download the image from `URL` and use it on your `ImageView`.

```
    im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_id); //add proper ImageView id not NetworkimageView id


    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(IMAGE_URL, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {
            im1.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use some 3rd party lib for Loading Images like Glide, fresco, picasso.

Why?
 1. To prevent my fav Out of Memory error when many a images are loaded eg list view.
 2. For fasting fetching of image
 3. For using it in the future. These images are stored in cache and you can use them in future without actually downloading them again. This helps in data saving and reduce wait time for user.

Comment: ok..can u tell me through coding..or any example u can give so tht i can understand

Comment: Simple to use, just write:   Glide.with(this).load("your image url").into(imageView);

Comment: May be this could help, excellent blog on Glide:  
[link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling)

Comment: volley also caches images.. no need to use other libs

Comment: only 1 line code? what library do we need to add and for my code it will be like this ?Glide.with(this)/load("IMAGE_URL").into(imageView)

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar I would recommend(not force) lib becoz of above 3 issues mentioned. Usage actually depends on the content of your app.

Comment: @z.al Read the github wiki of Glide. All the steps are mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Check volley networkimageview and use LruCache. You can find everything [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/). Just use LruCache. It is very simple and powerful. I have been using in many projects.

Steps to implement this

1. create class LruBitmapCache and download below file then copy the code

   > https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8oLTPOweId6cnFBamhFd3pva2c/view?usp=sharing
2. create an application class with name AppController and copy code from below file

   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8oLTPOweId6T1VEdlVTeWwxUTQ/view?usp=sharing
3. in xml include this view in place of imageview

   ```
   <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
   ```
4. In activity

   ```
   NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
               .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

   ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

   thumbNail.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
   ```

Comment: ImageRequest is not required. Instead of ImageView user networkImageview. Then simple single to load the image.
     im1.setImageUrl("url", imageLoader). check this url. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: i have updated my code..i have added networkImageview

Comment: @z.al add 2 more libs `import com.android.volley.Request;` and
`import com.android.volley.Response;`

Comment: ImageRequest is not required to load image.. In xml did u put networkImageview  user ImageView.. Go through some wiki to get idea of networkimage view

Comment: can u tell me what to do with my code...i m too much stressed out now...

Comment: @z.al included the steps to implement that... chk it